# C - Segmentation Fault with argv

Tags: c, argv

The code compiles and runs just fine, unless if I specify only one command line option, then it segfaults.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void printHelp()
{
    printf("Usage: fstring [ char ] [ amount ] Optional:[ outfile ]\n"
           "Example: fstring A 100 out.txt\n");
    exit(1);
}

char *f_string(const char *s, int t)
{
    int i; char *dst = malloc(t * strlen(s) + 1);
    for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        strcat(dst, s);
    }
    return dst;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("You need at least two arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *res = f_string(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    puts(res);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

As I said, if I give it two arguments, it runs, and if I give it none it prints the error message, but giving it just one causes the segfault. I do not understand why.

Comment: put `*dst=0` before for-loop at `f_string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **argc** - argument count
>
> **argv** - arg's value

**Change:**

```
if(argc < 2) {
```

**To:**

```
if(argc < 3) {
```

Read more about command line args here:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `argc` is not the number of args (if it were, the OP's code would work), but the number of args plus 1. In other words, `argc` is the length of the `argv` vector, not counting the terminating NULL.

Comment: @user4815162342 His `argv[2]` was always null because he was not executing his program with enough args. Changing  `argc` forces the user to add the appropriate number of args to run the program.

Comment: Yes thank you for helping me understand argc better.

Comment: @user3408678 Anytime!

Comment: It is clear that the program was being executed with too few arguments. I was referrng to the part of your response claiming that ***argc** - argument count*. `argc` is in fact by one larger than the number of arguments passed, which is why he must write `if (argc < 3)` although the script expects at least 2 arguments. A similar misunderstanding of the meaning of `argc` is what led to the bug in the first place.

Comment: @user4815162342 He needed a simple fix, I made it a simple answer. I left a link for more explanation. Too much, too fast can be overwhelming.

Comment: Simplicity is fine, but the answer is (partly) incorrect. The incorrect part perpetuates the confusion, while failing to explain **why** the OP's code was wrong and the fix works.

Comment: You are really upset about this. It was a simply off-by-one error.

Comment: @user4815162342 It's ok that you downvoted me. I still was able to help him.

Answer (score 7):

As `argc` contains the number of arguments passed to the program increased by 1, the test needs to be `if (argc < 3)`.

(`argc` is the length of the `argv` array, which includes the program name as `argv[0]`. A useful mnemonic is that `argv[argc]` is always NULL.)

Comment: I never knew that `argv[argc]` would be `NULL`. So, is this true `argv[argc]==argv[argc+1]==argv[argc+2]==...==NULL`?

Comment: @CoolGuy No, `argv[argc+1]` and beyond are undefined behavior. `argv` ends with a single NULL pointer, which allows it to be passed to functions without `argc` (which can be calculated from `argv` when necessary). Think of it as the pointer equivalent of a zero-terminated string.